# Class default constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, default-constructor

Assuming that we have the class `TestClass` in our C++ project. A default constructor is the one empty parameters list. So we have:

```
TestClass();
TestClass(int defaultParam = 0);
```

Can these two be considered default constructors? And if they can be, is it ethical to have a default constructor like the second line?

Comment: have you tried compiling it?

Comment: sincerely, no. I consider this an hypothetical situation. Also, if I know well, the compiler will alert you about such a situation only if you need to initialize a class with the default constructor.

Comment: then try it - see if it even compiles?

Comment: Well by definition (C++11[class.ctor]p5) default ctor is any ctor which can be called without arguments. But you can't have many default ctors (unless you use SFINAE).

Comment: @Abyx: depends what you mean. it's okay to have them, but can't use default initialization then.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yes, exactly. However I have no idea why one would want to write `T::T()` which can't be used.

Answer (score 2):

Either of

```
TestClass(void);
TestClass(int defaultParam=0);
```

can be used as the default constructor. When you have both, it is a problem since the compiler cannot distinguish between the two when the compiler needs to use a default constructor. E.g.

```
TestClass anObject;
TestClass objectArray[5];
```

**Unrelated to your question**

For stylistic reasons, you should use:

```
TestClass();
```

instead of

```
TestClass(void);
```

The second form is supported by C++ but it's not necessary. The argument type `void` is necessary only when declaring functions in C.

Comment: That's why I asked, because I was going to have both of them.

Comment: `(void)` is not really an idiom, more a necessity. `int foo()` in C means that `foo` takes any number of arguments so `foo(42)` compiles, which is bad. To fix it you write `int foo(void)` instead so that `foo(42)` will not compile. In C++ `int foo()` takes no arguments and `foo(42)` does not compile, therefore the `void` is useless noise.

Comment: @nwp I say it's an idiom because you don't need to declare `int foo(void)` to make a call `foo()`. It helps prevents calls `foo(42)` from being compiled. If you declare `int foo()` and use `foo(42)`, the error detection will be delayed until link time.

Comment: oh no, i almost reduced myself to anonymous upvoting of comment. anyway, @nwp is right. and in C++ the `void` is just needless verbosity.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I agree with both of you about the use of `void` in C++. I was commenting on whether use of `void` in `foo(void)` in C is a necessity or an idiomatic preference.

Comment: @RSahu: oh. in that case i can't make sense of "the error detection will be delayed until link time", because a C compiler doesn't generate very much ornamentation on the object code names (name mangling). in some situations (e.g. stdcall convention in Windows) i can envision that you *can* get such link time detection, if the total argument size is wrong. but i'm fairly sure that that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @RSahu What do you mean "the error detection will be delayed until link time"? There is not error here, declaring `int foo()` and calling it like `foo(42)` is correct C-code as far as I know.

Comment: @nwp My bad. For some reason I thought that if a call `foo(42)` is made and only a `foo()` is defined, the linker will show an error since there is no `foo(int)`. I have been using C++ for too long :) :)

Comment: you can also use "explicit" keyword

Answer (score 0):

having more than 1 constructor is called constructor overloading. If there are two default constructors it will generate an error as the compiler will not know which constructor to call while creating the object. If you  don't declare a default constructor the complier does it by itself.